# Difference between 这个 and 本

Tags: word-choice, difference

There are two words in Chinese that are both translated as “***This***” in English (**这个** and **本**). What is the difference between them and how to use them correctly ?

Comment: Can you give an example where 本 is translated as "This"?

Answer (score 4):

1. When 本 is used with an identity (person, company) it is exclusively referring to the first-person, and  这 is mostly referring to the third-person (some people do refer to oneself in the third-person)

Example:

这个人 (this person - the third-person)

这位法官 = this judge (the third-person)

这間公司 = this company (the third-person)

本人 = this person (the first-person) -->  this person (I myself)

本官 = this judge (the first-person) -->  this judge, (I myself)

本公司 = this company (the first-person) --> this company (our company)

Notice:

[本 + identity] is not always a "humbling word" for example 本大少爺 means 'This young master (I)'

2. 本 means 'this/ **current**' when it is used with time. The difference between [这个星期六，今個世紀 ，今年] and [本週六，本世紀，本年度] is the former is more colloquial and the latter is more literary
3. '本地' is a compound word meaning 'local/ domestic' (adj) e.g. '本地品牌' or  'this land'; 本土 is a compound word meaning 'native' e.g. 本土品牌 or 'mainland' e.g. 日本本土

Comment: I was thinking of this as well, but I would not translate it to "this" in this context. It is worth it to say that 本 is only used in formal writing where the recipient is of higher status than you. In this case, 本 corresponds to 貴 (you).

Comment: @ player3236 本座，本王，本大少爺 are certainly used by people in higher status than you

Comment: The word I was looking for is "humbling word", I guess

Comment: Found the word: 謙稱. There is also 本月，本年，是日etc., where the translation is indeed "this".

Comment: 在下，小人，小弟，愚兄，卑人 are 謙稱 (humble words); 本人 is a   formal word and it is neutral. Example" (colloquial) "我不想再辯論下去了";  ( literary) "本人不欲再辯"

Comment: Probably just an issue of interpretation. ["而形容寫信人即自己時，則可換上謙稱，如「敝機構」、「本人」、「晚輩」、「僕」、「弟」等等"](https://stedu.stheadline.com/sec/article/16547/書信格式-你識唔識)

Comment: 本人 may be a polite term, but 本 is neutral.  e.g. 本大少爺 is certainly not a polite/ humble term

Comment: We sometimes use "the present..." in English to achieve this distinction: e.g. "*The present* (本) paper adapts *this* (这个) research to...".

Answer (score 0):

Register.

这个 is neutral to colloquial in register, whereas 本 is very formal and almost exclusively used in writing.

此 and 该 are two other formal options, both roughly equal in formality to 本.

Note that 本 is also a classifier for things like books, so you may see something like 这本书. This usage is completely separate from the formal usage.